# FOSMessageBundle sending a message error

Tags: php, symfony

i would like to send a message via  FOSMessageBundle so i create a controller witch contain a method named send, after that i got an error in this instuction :

```
$sender = $this->get('fos_message.sender');
$sender->send($message);
```

the error message is :

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to FOS\MessageBundle\Sender\Sender::send() must implement interface FOS\MessageBundle\Model\MessageInterface, instance of FOS\MessageBundle\MessageBuilder\NewThreadMessageBuilder given, called in /projet/pivotalpartnersbo/src/Application/Sonata/MessageBundle/Controller/MessageController.php on line 32
```

Comment: Just be sure to pass a `MessageInterface` instance to send method, the error message is clear.

Comment: You need to get the message from the builder and pass that in like `$sender->send($builder->getMessage());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message must me created.

Something like 
`$message = $builder->newThread();` or `$message = $builder->reply($thread);`

While you apparently have just `$message = $builder;`

Answer (score 0):

thanks [qooplmao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1791606/qooplmao) and [yonel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4224384/yonel) i just find the mistake, that i forget to extend the BaseMessage in the class of $message object.
BaseMessage implement the MessageInterface.